# Javascript function difference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between this

```
const handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
        
}
```

...and this

```
const handleChange = (panel, event, expanded) => {

}
```

The second way breaks the application and ive been trying to find some material on how they differ. The code is part of an event handler for a react expansion panel with the expansion of the panel being controlled by aforementioned event.

```
<ExpansionPanel
id={`${mfeId}+'_'+${course.id}_CoursePanel`}
expanded={expanded === 'panel_'+course.id}
onChange={handleChange('panel_'+course.id)}
variant={'card'}
className={classes.courseExpansionPanel}
                        >
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The first one is a function that returns a function, the second one is not (unless it does that in the code you didn't post).

Comment: The first one is also called a higher order function (function that returns a function)

Comment: The reason your code breaks with the 2nd function is that the onChange prop needs to receive a function, but "handleChange('panel_'+course.id)" executes handleChange with the given arguments right there. Your handleChange function will probably fail becuase it's called with only 1 argument. The event and expanded arguments are undefined. Even if it wouldn't fail there, the onChange prop will receive it's result, which is not a function, which than will fail.

Comment: To use the 2nd handleChange, you would have to pass it like this:
onChange={(event, expanded) => handleChange('panel_'+course.id, event, expanded)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Javascript is a dynamically typed language, it does have types and it's instructive to think in terms of them in cases like this. Let's change it to the simplest possible analogy:

```
const add = a => (b, c) => a + b + c;
const otherAdd = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;
```

The first is a function that takes a number and returns a function that takes two numbers and then *that* function returns the sum. The other is a function that just takes 3 numbers and returns the sum.

What happens when you substitute one for the other?

```
2 - add(2, 3, 4);   // Error! You can't subtract a function from 2 (third argument is silently ignored!)
4 + otherAdd(2, 3); // Nonsense result! c will be undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a function with one argument (panel) that returns a new function, that takes 2 additional arguments (event, expanded)

You need to invoke both functions to execute the code inside:

```
handleChange(panel)(event, expanded)
```

It is a shorthand of:

```js
const handleChange = (panel) => {
  return (event, expanded) => {
     ....
  }
}
```

The second is just a simple function that takes three arguments, you can use it as:

```
handleChange(panel, event, expanded)
```

As you can see, while both options execute the same code they are invoked in a different way: your code could only possibily work with one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

The process you showed is called [`currying`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) - transforming a function taking multiple arguments into a function taking one argument and returning another function taking further arguments.

```
const handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
        
}
```

Takes one argument (`panel`) and returns function with two arguments (`event` and `expanded`).

```
const handleChange = (panel, event, expanded) => {

}
```

Takes three arguments and returns value.

Comment: Pedantic nitpick: it's partial application. If it were currying, it would take the arguments one at a time.